# my function in c++ is not passing through a variable correctly

Tags: c++, void

I am relatively new to c++ (only been coding in this language for about a week) and I think that in one of my void functions a variable isn't getting passed through correctly (this is just what I think the problem could be something different) here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mainProcess (string, string, int, double);
int main(){
    
    //input
    
    string name;
    string carType;
    string carModel;
    int daysOfHire;
    double totalPrice;
    
    cout << "what is the name\n";
    cin >> name;
    
    cout <<"what is the car type\n";
    cin >> carType;
    cout <<"what is the car model\n";
    cin >> carModel;
    cout <<"how many days of hire\n";
    cin >> daysOfHire ;
    
    //process
        
        mainProcess(carType, carModel, daysOfHire, totalPrice);
        
    //output
    
    cout <<"name: " <<name<< endl;
    cout <<"car type: " <<carType<< endl;
    cout <<"car model: " <<carModel<< endl;
    cout << "days of hire: " <<daysOfHire<< endl;
    cout <<"total bill: $" <<totalPrice<< endl;  //this line is supposed to print the totalPrice variable which was declared below
}

void mainProcess(string carType, string carModel, int daysOfHire, double totalPrice){
    if (carType == "family" && carModel == "saloon"){
        totalPrice = daysOfHire*33.00;
    }

    else if (carType == "family" && carModel == "hatchback"){
        totalPrice = daysOfHire*33.99;
    }

    else if (carType == "sports" && carModel == "reliant"){
        totalPrice = daysOfHire*40.00;
    }

    else if (carType == "sports" && carModel == "supa fast"){
        totalPrice = daysOfHire*80.00;
    }

    else if (carType == "city" && carModel == "executive"){
        totalPrice = daysOfHire*100.00;
    }

}
```

Comment: in `mainProcess`, `totalPrice` is a variable local to that function. You need to return the result (alternatively, you could pass `totalPrice` by reference)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `totalPrice` into `mainProcess` by value, this means that a copy is made and the changes are made to a local copy of it, not to the original. This is why `totalPrice` in `main` remains unchanged (and uninitialized!).

To make `totalPrice` become modifiable from inside, you need to pass it by reference, like this:

```
void mainProcess(string carType, string carModel, int daysOfHire, double& totalPrice) {
    // now assignment to totalPrice will change the original
    ...
}
```

Such parameters are called "output" or "in-out" parameters. However in this case there is no need to use an output parameter, because it's better to just return a needed value from the function. Also it's good to give functions names that have semantic meaning. Look how much easier to read the program becomes:

```
double calculateTotalPrice(string carType, string carModel, int daysOfHire){
    if (carType == "family" && carModel == "saloon"){
        return daysOfHire*33.00;
    }    
    else if (carType == "family" && carModel == "hatchback"){
        return daysOfHire*33.99;
    } 
    else if (carType == "sports" && carModel == "reliant"){
        return daysOfHire*40.00;
    }
    // ... etc    
}

...
const auto totalPrice = calculateTotalPrice(carType, carModel, daysOfHire);
```